# How do I access wity python ctypes to array values returned with a pointer from a dll coded in Delphi?

Tags: python, arrays, delphi, pointers, ctypes

I have a Delphi library that is exposing a results with a procedure like this:

```pascal
procedure Script_GetFindedList(List : Pointer; out Len : Cardinal); stdcall;
var X : TArray<Cardinal>;
begin
  TScriptMethod.Create(SCGetFindedList).SendExecMethod.Free;
  NamedPipe.WaitForReply(Pipe_WaitDelay);
  if not ResultReady then ExitProcess(0);
  SetLength(X,FuncResultStream.Size div 4);
  FuncResultStream.Read(X[0],FuncResultStream.Size);
  Len := Length(X) * 4;
  if Assigned(List) then
    Move(X[0],PByteArray(List)^[0],Len);
end;
```

And I am able to call it from normal delphi Code like this:

```pascal
function TFindEngine.GetFindedList : TArray<Cardinal>;
var BufLen : Cardinal;
begin
  Script_GetFindedList(nil, BufLen);
  if BufLen = 0 then Exit;
  SetLength(Result,BufLen div 4);
  Script_GetFindedList(PByteArray(Result), BufLen);
end;
```

I would like to wrap the code in Python using the ctypes library and I have some code like this:

```py
from ctypes import *

my_dll = windll.Script

def GetFindedList():
    my_dll.Script_GetFindedList.argtypes = [POINTER(c_uint), POINTER(c_uint)]
    my_dll.Script_GetFindedList.restype = None

    BufLen = c_uint()

    my_dll.Script_GetFindedList(None, byref(BufLen))
    if BufLen.value > 0:
        print("BufLen.value : {}".format(BufLen.value))

        ##################################################################
        # alternate solution that just leaks memory while doing nothind
        # buf = array('I', range(BufLen.value))
        # addr, count = buf.buffer_info()
        # Result = cast(addr, POINTER( (c_uint * BufLen.value) ))

        Result = (c_uint * BufLen.value)()

        print("Result before: {}".format(list(Result)))

        my_dll.Script_GetFindedList(byref(Result), byref(BufLen))       
        print("Result after: {}".format(list(Result)))

        return Result
    else:
        return []
```

But this is not working: I just get the correct BufLen.value but then, with the second call to dll I am not able to populate my array. I did many similar tries, but with no luck. Is there someone that can advise me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd call it like this:

```py
from ctypes import *
my_dll = windll.Script
my_dll.Script_GetFindedList.restype = None
size = c_uint()
my_dll.Script_GetFindedList(None, byref(size))
result = (c_uint*(size.value//4))()
my_dll.Script_GetFindedList(result, byref(size))
result = list(result)
```

This function would be much better if you return buffer length rather than size.

I tested this using the following code:

**Delphi**

```delphi
library TestDLL;

procedure Script_GetFindedList(List : Pointer; out Len : Cardinal); stdcall;
var
  X: TArray<Cardinal>;
begin
  X := TArray<Cardinal>.Create(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);
  Len := Length(X) * 4;
  if Assigned(List) then
    Move(Pointer(X)^, List^, Len);
end;

exports
  Script_GetFindedList;

begin
end.
```

**Python**

```py
from ctypes import *
my_dll = WinDLL(r'full/path/to/TestDLL.dll')
my_dll.Script_GetFindedList.restype = None
size = c_uint()
my_dll.Script_GetFindedList(None, byref(size))
result = (c_uint*(size.value//4))()
my_dll.Script_GetFindedList(result, byref(size))
result = list(result)
print result
```

**Output**

```
[1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L]
```

Comment: I get an error this way: usupported operand type(s) for /: '_ctypes.PyCArrayType' and 'int'

Comment: OK, try the update which adds the missing parens. But what you really should do is change the Delphi to return the length rather than the size. You should also take care with naming. Use `length` or `len` to indicate element count. Use `size` to indicate byte count. As it stands, your Delphi code uses `len` to mean something that is a `size`.

Comment: Problem is that I don't have direct control over Delphi interface (bt I can ask for a change). I am on Python 3 so I had to code it so: `result = (c_uint*(size.value//4))()`, but i still get error:  `expected LP_c_ulong istead of pointer to c_ulong_Array_27`    Should i cast it?

Comment: You are still setting `argtypes` I guess. Notice that I removed that. You should do the same. You don't need it.

Comment: You're right, I did many tries and I had it in more than one line. Now I removed it every where, but I still have access violation errors. :(

Comment: OK, I'll take a closer look. FWIW, `PByteArray(List)^[0]` is pointless. Use `List^`.

Comment: My Delphi function is already defined with stdcall in the header.    `procedure Script_GetFindedList(List : Pointer; out Len : Cardinal); stdcall;`    Should I make it `stdcall` also in the declaration?

Comment: No, it's fine in the interface section. I'll dig deeper.

Comment: OK, I wrote a simple test. The code in the question is fine. If you get AVs, then it's not due to the ctypes parameter passing. You can paste the code from my test to confirm what I say. Then you can look for the problem elsewhere. I believe that I have solved the ctypes issue that is the subject of this question.

Comment: This illustrates an important point when tackling such a problem. You suspect that the issue is with the ctypes interop. But the code you are calling has much more than plain interop. So the way to ensure the interop is right is to create an artificially simple test DLL that does nothing more than necessary to test the interop. Then if you cannot make it work, you know the issue is the interop. Once you make it work, you know that you've solved the interop issue, and remaining faults are unrelated to that. Breaking a problem down into small simple pieces is how you make progress.

Comment: @eryksun You mean I can pass result rather than byref(result)? I had not realised that. Thanks!

Comment: @eryksun Thanks. I get it. I updated the answer. Passing `result` is what's needed here.